# Python: create a list containing dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

how would you turn this string:

```
str='ldap:alberthwang,eeid:67739|ldap:meng,eeid:107,building:CL5'
```

into a list that give you this:

```
print x[1]['building']=CL5
```

which would be:

```
x=[{'ldap':'alberthwang','eeid':'67739'},{'ldap':'meng','eeid':'107','building':'CL5'}]
```

i've tried to split the string first and append to a list:

```
sample=[]
for s in str.split('|'):
  sample.append(s)
```

But i'm stuck on how to turn the list items into a dictionary that i can then use to populate another list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text='ldap:alberthwang,eeid:67739|ldap:meng,eeid:107,building:CL5'
sample=[
    dict(item.split(':') for item in part.split(','))
    for part in text.split('|')]
print(sample)
# [{'eeid': '67739', 'ldap': 'alberthwang'}, {'building': 'CL5', 'eeid': '107', 'ldap': 'meng'}]

print(sample[1]['building'])
# CL5
```

1. [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are a very convenient way to construct
   lists such as this.
2. A [dict can be constructed](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) from an iterable of key-value pairs. The iterable used above was a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).
3. `str` is a built-in type, so assigning a string to `str` overwrites
   the builtin. It's better to choose some other variable name to avoid
   future surprising bugs.

---

I read and write list comprehensions backwards:

```
[ expression            # (3)
  for variable in       # (2)
  iterable              # (1)
]
```

(1): First, understand the iterable. In the solution above, this is `text.split('|')`.

(2): `for variable in` causes `variable` to be assigned to the values in `iterable`, one at a time.

(3): Finally, `expression` can be any Python expression, (usually) using `variable`.

The syntax for generator expressions is almost the same. The difference between a list comprehension and a generator expression is that a list comprehension returns a list, while a generator expression returns an iterator -- an object that yields its contents on-demand (as it is looped over, or when `next` is called) instead of generating all the items at once as is the case with `list`s.

A list can consume a lot of memory if the list is long.
A generator expression will consume less memory (and can even be infinite) because not all elements have to exist in memory at the same time.

Comment: I'm definitely going to spend a lot of time wrapping my head around list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

Using `str` as a variable name is a bad idea, since it overshadows the built-in [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str).

```
s ='ldap:alberthwang,eeid:67739|ldap:meng,eeid:107,building:CL5'
res = [dict(colonStr.split(':') for colonStr in ds.split(','))
       for ds in s.split('|')]
```

stores the result you what in `res`.

Answer (score 0):

The key insight here is that `dict` can take a list of key/value pairs. So, you can do this using a comprehension like this:

```
string = 'ldap:alberthwang,eeid:67739|ldap:meng,eeid:107,building:CL5'

list_of_dicts = [dict(item.split(':') for item in items.split(',')) for items in string.split('|')]
print list_of_dicts
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

```
>>> s = 'ldap:alberthwang,eeid:67739|ldap:meng,eeid:107,building:CL5'
>>> x = [dict([d.split(':') for d in ls.split(',')]) for ls in s.split('|')]
>>> x[1]['building']
>>> 'CL5'
```